# MacBook Air 2018 lagging even in Recovery Mode

Tags: mac, battery, recovery

My MacBook Air battery is totally in nonworking condition, as soon I remove the charging cable it shuts down. Recently my laptop became very sluggish, even the wallpaper won't load. I am not able to use it at all, but after erasing the hard disk, and reinstalling macOS, it still lags, and even in Recovery Mode. I have no clue what has gone wrong.
Can anyone please suggest to me what I can do?

Comment: Get a replacement battery?

Answer (score 1):

If the battery cannot provide sufficient power, then the laptop will throttle the CPU. The laptop is not designed to run at high power levels directly from the mains cable, without a functioning battery.

In short: you need a new battery for your MBA to work properly.

Note that since Monterey, you should never need to reinstall the OS as a solution to most problems: at most you can erase all user content and data from System Preferences (Settings).

But if the problem still appears in Recovery mode; or with a new user account in Safe Boot mode, then it's likely not a software problem.